# What does "compatible"mean with respect to topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

I am reading through Stephen Woolard's General topology and I am not sure what he means by "compatible".

The context is as follows. $X$ is a topological space space, and $\delta$ is a [proximity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space) on $X$. I am confused by what is meant when he says:

> $\delta$ is compatible with the topology on $X$.

Does he mean that for any two subsets $A,B\subseteq X$ we have $A\delta B \iff \overline{A}\cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$? (here $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ in the topology).

Comment: Do you mean Stephen **Willard**'s *General Topology* or is there an actually topology book by Stephen Woolard?

Comment: I dk. But the 8th (and last) chapter of General Topology by R. Engelking is entirely about Proximity Spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means the following: a proximity $\delta$ induces a closure operator: $\overline{A} = \{x: \{x\}\delta A\}$ and this defines a topology in the usual way (closed sets are sets equal to their closure, open sets are their complement etc. ) If this topology equals the original topology on $X$, this topology is compatible with the proximity.

Comment: I was thinking it was this! Thanks.